# RestOperation exchange rejects cookie

Tags: java, rest, cookies

I have a class which checks the health status of a REST-Interface. It works nice but my log files are full of these warnings:

```
2017-08-23 03:59:58.707  WARN 1849 --- [io-13811-exec-5] o.a.h.c.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies  : Cookie rejected [JSESSIONID="14747303A2F23D4BE6DBAE0F282DEA94", version:0, domain:dealersearch.....com, path:/DCRMBroker/, expiry:null] Illegal 'path' attribute "/DCRMBroker/". Path of origin: "/system/healthcheck.jsp"
```

It seems the requests do not accept any cookies. I do not understand what is going on and how to accept them to get around the masses of log messages.

My health check class:

```java
package com......commons.health;

import com.....commons.health.HealthResult.Health;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations;

public abstract class RestHealthCheck extends HealthCheck {
private static final Logger LOGGER =     LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestHealthCheck.class);

public RestHealthCheck() {}

public abstract String getUrl();

public abstract RestOperations getRestOperations();

public HealthResult getHealthResult() {
    HealthResult result = new HealthResult();
    result.setName(this.getName());
    result.setHealth(Health.HEALTHY);
    result.setMessage((String)null);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);

    try {
        this.getRestOperations().exchange(this.getUrl(), HttpMethod.HEAD, entity, String.class, new Object[0]);
    } catch (Exception var5) {
        LOGGER.trace("Health check failed", var5);
        result.setHealth(Health.UNHEALTHY);
        result.setMessage(var5.getMessage());
    }

    return result;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An URL `http://server.example.com/system/healthcheck.jsp` is requested and the response contained a cookie that is defined for the URL `http://server.example.com/DCRMBroker/`.

The URLs are different and a client worth its name should reject that which happens here leading to the logs. The information you gave is not enough to say for sure who the culprit is. It can be the JSP-page setting a wrong cookie, it might be a forwarding rule on the server, so the JSP-page is internally forwarded to a different resource without changing the path within the response. It might also be something on your client where some kind of redirection takes place leading to this effect.

Maybe my explanations help you to track the reason down. If it's something on your side, you can fix that. If it's something on the other side, you might get in contact with them in order to let that fix that. Alternatively you can check your client if you can switch off the warning for this particular case so your log becomes calm again.

Comment: Thank you. It turned out the most useful way was to change the logging level for the particular package.  What I did was editing my application.properties with logging.level.org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies=ERROR